# Getting JSON from Google for Highmaps

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, highmaps

I'm pretty rusty with JavaScript, so I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm working with Highmaps and would like to link the map to data in a Google Spreadsheet. (It's a U.S. map of counties which will be updated regularly, so having it all in the script itself is a little unwieldy.)

This is what my code looks like now:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var example = 'us-counties',
  theme = 'default';

  (function($) { // encapsulate jQuery
  $(function() {
          var data = [{
              "code": "us-al-001",
              "name": "Autauga County, AL",
              "value": 0
          },
```

…

```
          {
              "code": "us-pr-153",
              "name": "Yauco Municipio, PR",
              "value": 0
          }],
          countiesMap = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all-all']),
          lines = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all-all'], 'mapline'),
          options;

      // Add state acronym for tooltip
      Highcharts.each(countiesMap, function(mapPoint) {
          mapPoint.name = mapPoint.name + ' County, ' + mapPoint.properties['hc-key'].substr(3, 2);
      });

          series: [{
              name: 'County',
              mapData: countiesMap,
              data: data,
              joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
              tooltip: {
                  enabled: true,
                  positioner: function () {
                    return { x: 0, y: 250 };
                    },
                  pointFormat: '{point.name}',
                  borders: 0.5
                },
              borderWidth: 0.5
          }, {
              type: 'mapline',
              name: 'State borders',
              data: [lines[0]],
              color: 'white'
          }, {
              type: 'mapline',
              name: 'Separator',
              data: [lines[1]],
              color: 'gray'
          }]
      };

      // Instanciate the map
      $('#container').highcharts('Map', options);
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#view-menu").click(function(e) {
          $("#wrap").toggleClass("toggled");
      });
      $("#sidebar-close").click(function(e) {
          $("#wrap").removeClass("toggled");
      });
  });
 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Of course, since there's over 3,200 counties, I'd rather store that data elsewhere and pull it into the `var data = []` string, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't something I've done, it looks like this should be relatively straightforward to do (although nothing is as simple as it looks of course).

There is an API for Google Sheets (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) and you can Google examples of how to retrieve data - this one looks clear (https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json) although it does point out that there are newer versions of some of the relevant APIs.

If you pull in the JSON data from the Google Sheet you then just need to put the values into the 'value' element of your data variable.  You could do all of that within your main function or do it separately and pass it to your function as a parameter.